# What type of Stero Cord / Port do I have here?

Tags: audio

I'm having difficulty with a stereo cord that I have.

I wonder if this might be some kind of USB. Does anyone know what kind of cord/connection this is?[image]

Comment: I have to know...  Did you crop that original picture not realizing the other item was the answer to your question?  I'm a big fan of coincidences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to be the connector to the external DSP, pictured below the stereo here. Specifically, the second and fourth ports from the left. The stereo should have included two 20' cables for these.

[image]

For posterity, I derived the model to be Kenwood Excelon KVT-915DVD

Comment: Did you really just find the full version of the picture the OP used to answer the question?  That's awesome.

Comment: Totally by accident! It did offer reassurance that I was on the right track